# Calendars and Contacts Sync after iCloud transition

Tags: icloud, mobileme

I have a mobile.me account that handles the synching of my personal data (mail, icals and contacts) on my 4 devices (iPod, iPad, MacBook and iMac).

when I read the docs about iCloud, it seems that this magic synching will not work anymore on 3 of my devices (non Lion and non iOS5)...

Will my contacts/calendars on my iPod (2ndGen) will never be updated anymore?

Answer (score 1):

You're right, iCloud requires iOS 5 or later on iOS devices and OS X 10.7 (Lion) or later on Macs.

http://www.apple.com/icloud/setup/

http://www.apple.com/support/icloud/

I'm pretty sure you can still use cable sync to update the information on your older iOS devices so they can coexist when/if you migrate your Mobile me account to iCloud.

Comment: Once the iCloud account is set up, iCal 4.0.4 in SL can sync your calendar with it as well.  I haven't heard of any way to sync contacts yet.